# How to check If there is a constraint in a database through application code in scala

Tags: scala, slick, ddl, scalatest, unique-constraint

I have a table `A`. I write a procedure to create a UNIQUE constraint based on certain condition. So I may or may not have constraint. The database is MySQL.

Now I write a test for checking constraint in Scala. I should read DDL of the table `A` and see if there is a constraint `B`, if there is, I should write a code to check the functioning of the constraint.